# How to enable Spark in Datastax Datacenter?

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

Our current Datastax datacenter setup contain 6 nodes in which both Solr and graph
enabled

root@ip-10-10-5-36:~# cat /etc/default/dse | grep -E 'SOLR_ENABLED|GRAPH_ENABLED'

```
GRAPH_ENABLED=1
SOLR_ENABLED=1
```

root@ip-10-10-5-36:~# nodetool status

```
Datacenter: SearchGraph
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.10.5.56  456.58 MiB  1            ?       936a1ac0-6d5e-4a94-8953-d5b5a2016b92  rack1
UN  10.10.5.46  406.24 MiB  1            ?       3f41dc2a-2672-47a1-90b5-a7c2bf17fb50  rack1
UN  10.10.5.76  392.99 MiB  1            ?       29f8fe44-3431-465e-b682-5d24e37d41d7  rack2
UN  10.10.5.66  414.16 MiB  1            ?       1f7de531-ff51-4581-bdb8-d9a686f1099e  rack2
UN  10.10.5.86  424.3 MiB   1            ?       27d37833-56c8-44bd-bac0-7511b8bd74e8  rack2
UN  10.10.5.36  511.44 MiB  1            ?       0822145f-4225-4ad3-b2be-c995cc230830  rack1
```

We are planning to implement spark in our existing datacenter. My question is

1) Will enabling spark affect existing data and service in datastax ?.

2) Or instead of enabling SPARK_ENABLED=1, did we need to setup separate 
   datacenter for Spark ?

**Updated :**

3) How DC1 and DC2 connect each other in ring,  is it based on same  Cluster 
   name specified in **cluster_name:** parameter. 
   Conf file : /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

4) Is there any separate configuration need to specify spark master in  data
   center.

5) Did i need to specify SearchGraph (DC1) seed ip in Spark(DC2) seed
   configuration section ? Or just Spark seed ip only need to specify in DC2 
   Configuration section(cassandra:yaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to create separate datacenter for DSE Analytics. The full process [is described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/dseAnalyticsSolo.html).

Comment: Thanks, We had created separate DC for Spark work load. Our Cluster now contain 6 SearchGraph nodes in DC1 and 3 Spark nodes in DC2. We had altered the keyspace [as described in document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/dseAnalyticsSolo.html) and configured **cluster_name:** same in both Data-center. Now  both datacenter is showing in cluster.

Comment: I need some clarification on Data center connection in Cluster.                                                  **(1)** How DC1 and DC2 connect each other in ring,  is it based on same  Cluster name specified in **cluster_name:** parameter. **(2)** Is there any separate configuration need to specify spark master in  data center. **(3)**  Did i need to specify SearchGraph (DC1) seed ip in Spark(DC2) seed  configuration section ? Or just Spark seed ip only need to specify in DC2 Configuration section(Cassandra:yaml)

Comment: At least one node from each DC should be in the seed list for all nodes in both DCs (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html).

Answer (score 0):

to augment Alex's answer, this will depend if you'd like to execute Graph Analytics or not.  What type of Spark work will be preformed when it's enabled?